# How to calculate and get the smooth value for pitch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opengl-es, core-motion

I am trying to find a accurate angle (a) show in below image.

[image]

By researching I understand that I can get the angle using **CMotionManger**. I created a singleton class which will give me updates regarding device movement. And getting the "**Pitch**" value using **CMQuaternion**

For better understanding what "Pitch" is with respect to axis, refer below image.

[image]

Here is my code in which I am getting expected value of pitch.is it the correct way to find the angle shown in 1st image ?

```
- (void) startMotionUpdate {

if (self.motionManager == nil) {
    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
}

self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = kUpdateInterval;

[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical
                                                        toQueue:self.deviceQueue
                                                    withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        CGFloat x = motion.gravity.x;
        CGFloat y = motion.gravity.y;
        CGFloat z = motion.gravity.z;


        CMQuaternion quat = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion;
        double yaw = asin(2*(quat.x*quat.z - quat.w*quat.y));

        DLog(@"Yaw ==> %f", yaw);

        double myPitch = radiansToDegrees(atan2(2*(quat.x*quat.w + quat.y*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.x*quat.x - 2*quat.z*quat.z));

        DLog(@"myPitch ==> %.2f degree", myPitch);

        self.motionLastPitch = myPitch;
    }];
}];

}
```

In Log I am getting this print :

```
    [Line 64] myPitch ==> 74.71 degree
 [Line 60] Yaw ==> -0.037314
 [Line 64] myPitch ==> 74.68 degree
 [Line 60] Yaw ==> -0.037849
 [Line 64] myPitch ==> 74.67 degree
 [Line 60] Yaw ==> -0.038531
 [Line 64] myPitch ==> 74.69 degree
 [Line 60] Yaw ==> -0.038637
 [Line 64] myPitch ==> 74.71 degree
 [Line 60] Yaw ==> -0.037314
 [Line 64] myPitch ==> 74.68 degree
 [Line 60] Yaw ==> -0.037849
 [Line 64] myPitch ==> 75.65 degree
 [Line 60] Yaw ==> -0.038531
 [Line 64] myPitch ==> 76.90 degree
 [Line 60] Yaw ==> -0.038637
```

I have tried to place my phone as per first image, so is the values are right ?  If yes then how can I get the stable values for Pitch ?

Any help / Idea / guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think below are good reference this may help you.

[Using quaternion instead of roll, pitch and yaw to track device motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239482/using-quaternion-instead-of-roll-pitch-and-yaw-to-track-device-motion)

[iPhone - understanding iPhone rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170010/iphone-understanding-iphone-rotation)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock