# Transform device's attitude so that Z- axis is aligned with north and Y- is pointing gravity in CoreMotion?

Tags: ios, transform, coordinate-systems, core-motion

I use `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical` and this way rotation values roll, pitch and yaw are (0,0,0) when device is flat on table and X+ axis is pointing north.

What I would like to do is to have (0,0,0) values when Z- axis is pointing north and Y is now pointing at gravity? Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @RyanSullivan Nope, I modified other things in my app (used different axis to represent XYZ etc).